# deleteText material-table react alignment

Tags: reactjs, alignment, material-table

I use material-table (https://material-table.com/) for my react project and this component has many customization options. One of them *body.editRow.deleteText* refers to text that is displayed when user want delete one register.

But I want align right this text and I don't find this prop for customization. I now that this component use materialtable-ui and this alignment is on the propety *.MuiTableCell-root* but I don't now how to use this.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Just inspect the element in DOM for its class id and import custom css targeting that id like:

.some-cust-text { 
  yourcss
}

Comment: I tried this. I create File.css in same folder that File.jsx. Use _import './File.css';_ and decorate like this _<MaterialTable className="MuiTableCell-root"_. 

My File.css:

_.MuiTableCell-root {
    text-align: right;
}_. But doesn't worked